# Wildcard subdomains, block all other

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, centos

I'm having a few issues with my new VPS just bought. I'm trying to configure Apache to accept wildcare subdomains on my main website, but allowing this also means that I can't block all others except the one created.

To be more explicit, I'm having this:

`subdomain1.domain.com` -> redirects correctly (CNAME added, folder ok, everything ok)
`subdomain2.domain.com` -> same as subdomain1

`subdomainN.domain.com` -> the subdomainN doesn't exist. Thus, if I write "stackoverflowreallyrocks.domain.com" I'm being redirect to my stackoverflowreallyrocks.domain.com, with the content of domain.com - which isn't good.

Is there a way to redirect all subdomains that doesn't exists to domain.com?

The `httpd.conf` for the main domain is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/domain"
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
</Virtualhost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain1.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/domain/_subdomain1"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain2.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/domain/_domain2"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding another `VirtualHost` to the bottom of the config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *
    ServerAlias *
</Virtualhost>
```

The other `VirtualHost` entries should still match as they are better matches, and are prior to the wildcard host, allowing non-matching requests to fall into this last `VirtualHost`